# how to parse Json data with custom deserialization

Tags: android, json, kotlin, networking, retrofit

I'm sending API Call and getting response like that

```
{ "12312412312124123124": { "id": "12312412312124123124", "content": [ { "id": 41419969} ] },
"141412312412312521": { "id": 141412312412312521", "content": [ { "id": 41419969} ] }}
```

how can I handle to parse this json object or create data class for it , I've searched for custom deserialization but can't find answer...

This is my call execution code

```
   builder.build().newCall(request).execute().use { response ->

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val responseBody = response.body?.string()
          
            if (!responseBody.isNullOrBlank()) {
                val readings = gson.fromJson(responseBody, MyClassForParsing::class.java)
                
            } else {
                println("Response body is empty.")
            }
        } else {
            println("Request failed with code: ${response.code}")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer in case if it will help someone I'll post it here...

first you need to get as response JsonObject , like this :

```
suspend fun yourFunction() : JsonObject
```

then you need to store that JsonObject in a variable

```
val call = service.yourFunction()
```

then you need this function

```
 fun parseStringParameterWithGsonKotlinDynamicKey(stringParameter: String): Map<String, Any?> {
    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonObject = gson.fromJson(stringParameter, JsonObject::class.java)

    val parsedParameters = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
    for ((key, value) in jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        parsedParameters[key] = value
    }

    return parsedParameters
}
```

create another variable and call this function passing JsonObject as a String , like this

```
val dfg= parseStringParameterWithGsonKotlinDynamicKey(call.toString())
```

at that point you'll get parsed json object with your object in it and you can iterate and get your items like this

```
dfg.entries.forEach { item ->
       val devices = Gson().fromJson(item.value.toString(),YuorDataClass::class.java)
   }
```

I hope someone would find an answer and I will make someones day!

P.S. Thanks who responded!

Answer (score 1):

i am using retrofit to do networking. u can processing json to variabel too

u can read it here: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-retrofit-for-networking-in-android-for-beginners-ef6bae5ef113

Answer (score 0):

Response Data Class (Don't forget to add `@SerializedName`)

```
data class ResponseType(
    var id: String?,
    var content: List<Content>?
)

data class Content(
    var id: Int?
)
```

Variable key values ​​are available in the relevant json data

```
interface API {
    @GET("yourEndPoint")
    fun yourFunction(): Call<HashMap<String, ResponseType>>
}
```

Last Step call enqueue

```
val call = service.getYourApiRequestFunction()

call.enqueue(object : Callback<HashMap<String, ResponseType>> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<HashMap<String, ResponseType>>,
        response: Response<HashMap<String, ResponseType>>
    ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val responses = response.body()
            // your process - responses type ==== > HashMap<String, ResponseType>
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<HashMap<String, ResponseType>>, t: Throwable) {
        // your error case
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting an error  :                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, com.remotetech.network.models.AssetResponse>>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.